# Eigenspaces with 2 or more free variables

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm confused about the vectors that span an eigenspace when there is more than one free variable. If the matrix that has the eigenvectors as its nullspace has more than one free variable, can I call each vector of the basis for the nullspace an "eigenvector"? It seems confusing to me, because since they correspond to a single eigenvalue, shouldn't I call a linear combination of the two vectors an eigenvector, and nothing else? (corresponding to that eigenvalue)

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by "free variable" here. I may assume that it means your null space has dimension greater than $1$. Anyway, every vector in the null space is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $0$... Sorry, I don't really know what is being asked here.

Comment: @Tun, every *non-zero* vector in the nullspace is an eigenvector....

Comment: I think I didn't understand the definitions... I thought every eigenvector should correspond to a single eigenvalue.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for correcting that :)

Comment: Check this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249579/solving-a-system-of-linear-equations-to-find-two-eigenvectors).

Comment: @SamaraAssis It is true that every eigenvector corresponds to a single eigenvalue, but the correspondence is not one-to-one. One eigenvalue can (and usually) have infinitely many eigenvectors.

Comment: @SamaraAssis: You might like to read these two postings: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133584/how-do-i-find-the-basis-of-this-eigen-space, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88083/question-about-eigenspaces. Regards